# Call all unique Values from SPO List, threshold exceeded, into a drop down field

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, custom-form, list-view-threshold, unique

I have a custom table with drop down field, it need to show all unique value from a SharePoint online list.

The problem is it already exceeded the 5000 limit threshold. And upon my query, it is only able to find the unique value from top 5000 items.

The particular column is already indexed in SPO list.

Any suggestions !!

Comment: What is the data type of that column? Also, there are ways to fetch more than 5000 items using API calls.

Comment: Text Type and ID.  We are able to fetch all the data into custom data table and when we are trying to call it in a Selectpicker  (Bootstrap) it is not working !!

Comment: Would it be possible to extract all the values into a JavaScript hash-table and then insert all the unique values into a separate list with a unique, indexed field and then add new items are added check to see if the new value is present in the list and add only values which are not present? An attempt to insert a new, but duplicate record would predictably fail, but would also indicate that the value exists. I have dealt with lists which exceeded the 5000 item limit and members wanted to run analytics on the data so I used a second list to store values aggregated by date so that queries could